# Run C++ program with arguments iteratively using bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to run this program called cvp iteratively and passing these arguments with .gz being different files (ie. srv_0 to srv_20). How can i pass all arguments to the the cpp program called cvp? And run this program many times which is designated by the variable `a` and different files.

I tried this, really not sure how to do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
#testing script

for a in {1...5}
do
    ./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f srv_$a.gz >>README
done
```

Comment: Do you mean `cvp` where you wrote `cpp`? Please expand what you mean by `iteratively` and `pass all the arguments`.

Comment: @jhnc hi, the program compiled is called cvp. The program needs to pass in those arguments ` -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 ` and different files `-f srv_#` (a number ranging from 0 to 20 let's say) to run, and output some text to readme.

Comment: Use two dots (`{1..5}`) instead of three

Comment: @thatotherguy the real problem is i cannot pass in those arguments for this c++ program. my script does run for 5 times but the arguments are not being passed into the c++ program.

Comment: Do you want a range of names as parameters in a *single* call to an external program? Please do not comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your question.

Comment: I think your problem is in your C++ program. If I remove the third dot in the sequence expression, the `cvp` line expands to `./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f srv_1.gz` and so on. You can test your own expansion by prefixing the `cvp` line with `echo`.

Comment: ..although `echo ./cvp -v -w 256 -F 16,0,0,0,0 -f srv_$a.gz >>README` will send its output to the README file. Leave the `>>README` part off if you want to see the output "live". You can also add `set -x` to the script before these commands, and bash will print the commands (preceded by "+ ") as it executes them.